# Why the bibliography url does not show in color?

Tags: bibliographies, hyperref, citing, urls

Here is what I wrote

```
\documentclass[12pt, a4paper]{book}
\usepackage[colorlinks=true,breaklinks]{hyperref}
\usepackage[hyphenbreaks]{breakurl}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\definecolor{c1}{rgb}{0,0,1}
\definecolor{c2}{rgb}{0,0.3,0.9}
\definecolor{c3}{rgb}{0.3,0,0.9}
\hypersetup{linkcolor={c1},citecolor={c2},urlcolor={c3}}
\begin{document}
\begin{thebibliography}{}
\bibitem{beta}BetaFunction:https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beta function
\end{thebibliography}
\end{document}
```

and the outcome is [image: here]

and when I compile the file, the urls in bibliography do not show in blue color. How can I fix this?

Thank you.

Comment: Please provide an actual example of a bib entry that contains a `url` field.

Comment: @Mico I edited the question.

Comment: Your example is not an [MWE](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228/48973) which makes it hard for us to test. Howevver, it looks like you are just typing the URL without telling LaTeX that it is one. try `\url{https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beta}`.

Comment: @schtandard Thank you so much. I remember I learned it from a youtube I dont know how i forget to write url. its working now thank you so much.

Comment: @AliShadhar Great. Could you please modify your example into an MWE anyway? That is, it should start with `\documentclass`, end with `\end{document}` and run through LaTeX, producing the output you show.

Comment: @schtandard right on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to tell LaTeX that you are writing a URL:

```latex
\url{https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beta function}
```

---

If you are serious about using bibliographies, you should consider using `biblatex` instead of typing them manually, though.

Comment: Thanks again :) +1